# Display data from SQL database in html: returned data object empty

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, sql

I want to retrieve data from my SQL database and use it on my HTML page.

I have a php script `get_score.php` like this:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect( "localhost", "xxx1", "xxx2", "xxx3");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$sql = "SELECT `name`, `score` FROM crossstreet ORDER BY `score` DESC LIMIT 5";
if (!mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $output = ($row["name"]);
}
mysqli_free_result($result);
echo json_encode($result);

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

And then I want to retrieve the data I via JQuery. I have read about the cross-origin issue but the data I retrieve and the html/Jquery are on the same server.

```
$.get("get_score.php", function( data ) {
  console.log(window[data]);
}, "json" );
```

This returns `undefined`. If I make it `$(data)` it returns an object like the one on this screenshot.
[image]

Where is my mistake; how can I just get the data from the server to use in html?

Comment: You need to `json_encode($output)` not `$result`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make `$output` an array so you get all the rows.

```
$output = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $output[] = $row['name'];
}
```

Then you should echo this:

```
echo json_encode($output);
```

And in your jQuery code, you should do `console.log(data);`

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqli_free_result($result);
echo json_encode($result);
```

i think this is the problem.
Try to reverse the order. You are making the result free before using it.
Do like this, instead of the above .

```
echo json_encode($result);
mysqli_free_result($result);
```

Comment: `$result` is not useful to send to the client.